# how pass data between pages in php 5.5

Tags: php, isset

i have next code and have Notice: Undefined index: name
when open form page or empty fields
so how i solve it and i'm use php5.5

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])  == 'POST'){
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $mail = $_POST["mail"];
  $massage = $_POST["massage"];

  echo "$name";
  echo "$mail";
  echo "$massage";
}
```

Comment: isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) will return true if it is set, and you are comparing that with a string - so your comparison works like if ( 1 == 'POST' ), it will never work. if ( isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) returns what you try to do

Answer (score 4):

`iseet()` checks if a variable is set. Not if it has a specific value.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  == 'POST'){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])  && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @John Conde, but if you really wish to use `isset()` you could so in a way like:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])  && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){ //
```

or another way to do so:

Give your `<form>` a hidden type:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "">
<input type = "hidden" name = "check">
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

and then use it like:

```
if(isset($_POST['check'])) { //
```